# how to write an argument-size generic function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, a tcp server has the following methods to listen:

```
server.listen(port, [host], [backlog], [listeningListener])
server.listen(path, [listeningListener])
server.listen(handle, [listeningListener])
```

I would like to create an application specific server which calls this lower level tcp server. I would like to provide my users with a listen method which just calls the right listen method of a tcp server.

Is there a way for me to avoid writing three different listen methods, and passing their arguments to the three tcp server's listen methods? Will it pass on optional parameters?

Can I just do something like this (with slightly made up syntax):

```
myapp.listen(args*){
    tcpserver.listen(args*);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, [all of a function's arguments are always available under the name `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), whether or not they also have their own names; so you can write:

```
myapp.listen(){
    tcpserver.listen.apply(tcpserver, arguments);
}
```

using [the function `Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to forward `arguments` to the desired method-call.

---

**Edited to add:** I should also clarify that although this:

> In node.js, a tcp server has the following methods to listen […] the three tcp server's listen methods […]

is consistent with the way [the Node.js documentation describes things](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server), it's not *strictly* accurate. JavaScript doesn't have any concept of function/method overloading; rather, it must be that a `Server` object has a single `listen` method that examines its first argument to determine which "overload" to execute.